# What is advantages of using MTProto for Telegram over using HTTPS?

Tags: tls

Why did Telegram decide to make their own protocol? What I think is HTTPS is a kind of perfect encryption solution between server and client.

Comment: https is the perfect solution for *web* server and *web* client. For any other use-case, it has quite a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Rather than comparing MTProto to HTTPS (which is absurd), the question should be asking why they are not using established messaging protocols like XMPP; and why they are building their own encryption methods, instead of using PGP or TLS. While Telegram could give expanded explanation, I believe the real reason is probably NIH.

Comment: @LieRyan Understand your words. Thanks. But what do you mean by NIH?

Comment: @choiapril: [NIH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the *Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secured* is a special purpose protocol for web browsing and optimized for this use-case. [That doesn't stop people for using it for other purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), but this is not what the protocol was designed for.

[MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/techfaq) does not just define encryption, but also how individual chat messages and their metadata are structured. Because HTTPS is not a chat protocol, it doesn't have any useful specifications for anything like that. Also, chat protocols need to be able to push messages to clients without them polling the server all the time. HTTP(S) with its request-response model isn't built for that.

Another thing Telegram needs but which HTTPS does not provide is encryption between clients. HTTPS only provides encryption between client and server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more quick question. Then, a client-to-client protocol, such as TLS, means communications over TLS don't reach to server?

Comment: Additional question for this answer of yours. What's different b/w the encryption model of a pair of clients and that of a client and a server?

Comment: @choiapril TLS is not a "client-to-client" protocol. It is an underlying protocol for encrypted networking which HTTPS is built upon.

Comment: Okay. I'll look up more about that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @choiapril In MTProto, every message is first sent to the Telegram server and then sent to the receiver. With standard HTTPS, the server would decrypt the message and then reencrypt it with a different key for the receiver. That means the server can eavesdrop. To prevent that, the MTProto protocol encrypts in a way that only the actual receiver can read it and the server only forwards the encrypted message without being able to decrypt it.

Comment: Omg. Your words made me have the concept down cold. Thumbs up to you!

Comment: Btw, you explained that standard HTTPS would use 'a different key' for the receiver when a server sends the msg to the receiver. But I think when a server-to-client happens they use a same symmetric key with which the sender has encrypted the msg. Is that not the case if a chat message is being transmitted?